# Row yielded no match during lookup SSIS LookUp Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ssis, lookup, business-intelligence

I keep getting the error message

> Error: 0xC020901E at Data Flow Task,
>   Lookup ProjectId [580]: Row yielded no
>   match during lookup. Error: 0xC0047072
>   at Data Flow Task, DTS.Pipeline: No
>   object exists with the ID 880.

It does not reoccur in the same spot rather in different places each run.  Even when everything is exactly the same through 2 different runs.  Sometimes it doesn't even appear visually on a look up, although the error makes it pretty clear that is what's causing it.

Can anyone give me some incite to why this might be happening and some suggestions on how to fix it.  I am using Business Intelligence Studio 2005

I should probably note that I have the Lookups Error being Redirect Row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming because I did not have no caching enable, in 2005 it is very counter intuitive.  When the checkbox is not checked for caching it still does it.  When you check it but do not specify the size.  Then you are not caching. The option I needed and though had been enabled by default.